# non-type template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I know that non-type template argument for intgral type must be const expression so:

```
template <int E>
class cat
{
public:
    int array[E];
};

int main()
{
    cat<4> ob; // ??
}
```

From what I've read only `const` variables that get initialized with `const` expressions are `const` expressions. In this example, we have `int E = 4;`, so `E` will *not* be a `const`expression.

So why doesn't `cat<4> ob;` throw an error? Am I missing something here?
And how will `int array[E];` be created if `E` is not known at compile time?

Comment: `4` is a compile time constant.

Comment: @hmjd Im talking about E. when I did cat<4> ob; it like telling the compiler to create the variable E and set it to 4, and since E is non-const int. so the value of E will not be known at compile time. so array[E] will throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`E` is `4` before actual compilation starts. Template specialization takes place before that, which means that the code actually seen by the compiler is something like

```
 class cat4
 {
 public:
 int array[4];
 };

 int main()
 {
 cat4 ob;
 }
```

This is a fairly loose interpretation, don't take it ad-litteram.

To really test this scenario out, you can try:

```
 template <int E>
 class cat
 {
 public:
 int array[E];
 };

 int main()
 {
 int k = 4;
 cat<k > ob; // ??
 }
```

Comment: Im talking about E. when I did cat<4> ob; it like telling the compiler to create the variable E and set it to 4, and since E is non-const int. so the value of E will not be known at compile time

Comment: @AlexDan you're thinking about templates the wrong way. E is not a variable, it's a template parameter. IMO templates are closer to macros than they are to actual classes.

Comment: @AlexDan It's not accurate to call `E` a variable and in fact for all practical matters it doesn't vary.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore : so E will be replaced by the value 4. if it's true, than this explain everything to me.

Comment: @AlexDan yes, and by whatever other values you specialize the template on. You can also have `cat<5>` and `cat<1>` and they all generate different classes with different sizes for the inner array.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you read was rather incomplete.

Constant expressions also include literals (like `4`), enumerators, `sizeof` expressions, the results of `constexpr` functions with constant arguments (since 2011), as well as `const` variables. Any of these with integer type can be used as an integer template argument.

There are probably a few others that I haven't thought of, and any complex expression built from constant expressions is also a constant expression.